# What is this pink-flowering shrub in Massachusetts, and how can I transplant it?

Tags: identification, shrubs, transplanting

This pink-flowering shrub is in the sun in central Massachusetts. It bloomed profusely throughout May and June, and produced a few buds again in the fall. It grew to about 4 feet before we pruned it. We moved here last winter, so I don't know its age. We're putting an addition on the house, and it's in the way. It's not only beautiful, but is also a haven for sparrows, so we'd like to save it. Can someone please identify it, and tell me the best way to successfully transplant it? I'm concerned that the roots may extend under the abutting patio, which might make it difficult to dig up. Thank you!
[image][image][image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This plant is a cultivar of [Weigela florida](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weigela).  The variety called '[Nana Variegata](http://www.connonnurseries.com/index.cfm/fuseaction/plants.plantDetail/plant_id/2291/index.htm)' grows to four feet tall with light pink coloured flowers, cream and green foliage which blooms in spring.
Once described as being 'gloomy' in the garden the cultivars are quite different.  They flower reliably in late spring and will reflower in the summer.

The plant in the picture is well established and would not be my first candidate for moving. Unless you see paving slabs being pushed up I would leave it be. If you have to move it:

- dig a trench six inches deep around the perimeter of the foliage in the fall
- go back in the spring and dig it up
- be patient as you will have to move a root ball the diameter of the foliage if you want to have the best chance of success